# Meaning of (?^: ) in perl compiled regex

Tags: regex, perl

I've been trying to understand what the `qr//` construct does in perl.
I wrote the following test one-liner:

```
perl -e 'my $re=qr/b.+|c|d/; END {print "$re\n"}'
```

That outputs:

`(?^:b.+|c|d)`

And if I add `use 5.016`, E.g.:

```
perl -e 'use 5.016; my $re=qr/b.+|c|d/; END {say $re}'
```

I get:

`(?^u:b.+|c|d)`

What do the `(?^: ... )` and `(?^u: ... )` constructions mean, and what's the difference between them?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45418639/3832970

Comment: See the Perl docs. https://perldoc.perl.org/perl5140delta.html#Regular-Expressions. Really, inline modifiers are scoped and allow a temporary change as to how the regex behaves. This is taken/given based on what the external regex modifiers _were/are_, i.e. `=~ /rx/here`. So, if you had `//xsm`, you could temporarily change it to `(?i-xsm:abc)` which takes off the `//xsm` and adds the `//i`. The bright (relative term) people over there decided a new circumflex `^` modifier was called for `(?^:abc)` which sets the _`Perl defaults`_ as external modifiers.

Comment: And with something like `(?^u: ... )` it temporarily (scoped) sets the default's and adds the _`u`_ modifier. You can also do `(?^add-remove:...)` to tailor it to your needs.

Comment: It indicates what flags you provided to the regex compiler (e.g. `qr/.../i` would produce `(?^i:... )`). `^` means the default. `^u` means default plus `/u`. One of the features enabled by `use 5.016;` causes `/u` to be used by default.